Liferay Developer Studio Autometically closed in ubantu 22 version
When I open Liferay-Developer-Studio in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and try to write Something in JAVA class file or JSP File one Suffestion box will appear and then Liferay-Developer-Studio will closed Automatically and below errors are generated.
Ubuntu OS Detail / Configurations.

RAM / Memory : 16 G.B.
OS Version   : Ubuntu 22.04.4
Processor    : 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1155G7 @ 2.50GHz × 8


BELOW ERROR ARE GENERATED
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:  
  
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007190fc1b61f8, pid=4774, tid=4775    

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.22+7) (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1)    

Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

Problematic frame:    
C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xdb61f8]    
Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/st17102303 LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio/LiferayWorkspacewithDevStudio/liferay-developer-studio/core.4774)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
